# Angular Compiler Options path configuration

Tags: angular, angular-library, compiler-options

I am building an angular library(generated through cli).
Structure looks like this for multiple entry points

```
-projects
 -my-lib
  -src
   -lib
    -components-type-x
     -component-1
      -index.ts
      -public-api.ts
      -...
    -pubic-api.ts
   -ng-package.json
   -package.json
   -tsconfig.lib.json
   -tsconfig.lib.prod.json
```

Rest is like normal angular project.
What I am having problem with is configuring the paths that are used by compileroptions.

What I am getting when trying to build the lib

```
Building entry point '@xx/my-lib'
Building entry point '@xx/my-lib/src/lib/components-x/component-1'
```

What I want to see is

```
Building entry point '@xx/my-lib'
Building entry point '@xx/my-lib/components-x/component-1'
```

Have tried changing the paths either on tsconfig.json of the src project but also on tsconfig.lib.json like this but nothing.

```
"paths": {
  "@xx/my-lib": ["projects/my-lib/src/lib/public-api.ts"],
  "@xx/my-lib/*": ["projects/my-lib/src/lib/*/public-api.ts"]
}

"paths": {
  "@xx/my-lib": ["dist/my-lib"],
  "@xx/my-lib/*": ["dist/my-lib/*"]
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional path, which points to the src/lib folder. And in each component folder create an index.ts, which exports everything from public-api.ts.

tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": {
  "@xx/my-lib": ["projects/my-lib/src/lib/public-api.ts"],
  "@xx/my-lib/*": ["projects/my-lib/src/lib/*"]
}
```

components-1/index.ts:

```
export * from './public-api';
```

components-1/public-api.ts:

```
export * from './test.module';
export * from './test.component';
```

Importing a component should now look like this:

```
import { Component1} from '@xx/my-lib/components-x/component-1'
```

Directory Structure:

```
- projects
 - my-lib
  - src
   - lib
    - components-x
     - components-1
      - index.ts
      - public-api.ts
      - ... component files
```

Here is a link to a sample repository

https://github.com/hildegunstvonmythenmetz/ts-library-imports

Please take a look at the import of the component module in the app module.

Comment: Could you show me how the lib structure would look? Because I think I have done it as you said but just to be sure since it doesn't seem to change something.

Comment: Hello, I created a repository to illustrate how this issue can be resolved. Please take a look: https://github.com/hildegunstvonmythenmetz/ts-library-imports

Comment: Please let me know, if your problem is resolved and if so please be so kind to mark this as the correct answer.